# Why is PixiJS clipping this simple bitmap?

Tags: typescript, pixi.js

I'm attaching two bitmaps (`pixi.Sprite`) to an application that scales to fit the screen using an optimal ratio. It scales normally as I can see in the document inspector.

[image: Sample 1]

The problem is that at a bigger scale, the figure gets clipped:

[image: Sample 2]

Here's what inspection looks like using the cursor above the canvas:

[image: Sample 3]

Code for displaying the level:

```
export default class Level {
    // ...
    private _resizeListener: any = undefined;
    private _application: pixi.Application | undefined = undefined;
    // ...

    // ...

    async display(variables: LevelDisplayVariables) {
        // ...

        // Pixi application
        this._application = new pixi.Application({
            width: FRAME_WIDTH,
            height: FRAME_HEIGHT,
            backgroundColor: '#000',
        });
        document.body.querySelector('main')!.appendChild(this._application!.view as HTMLCanvasElement);

        const addNobody = () => {
            const orient = (sprite: pixi.Sprite) => {
                sprite.anchor.set(0.5);
                sprite.position.set(300, 400);
                sprite.rotation = 0;
            };
            const pixiStage = this._application!.stage;
            const shadow = new pixi.Sprite(pixi.Texture.from("assets/carShadow/car-shadow.png"));
            shadow.scale.set(1.3, 1.6);
            const car = new pixi.Sprite(pixi.Texture.from("assets/carSkins/porsche-carrera-gt.png"));
            pixiStage.addChild(shadow);
            pixiStage.addChild(car);
            orient(shadow);
            orient(car);
        };
        addNobody();

        // Resizing
        this._resizeListener = this._resizeFrame.bind(this);
        window.addEventListener('resize', this._resizeListener);
        this._resizeFrame();

        // ...
    }

    // ...

    private _resizeFrame() {
        if (!this._displaying) {
            return;
        }
        const ratio = optimalFitRatio(
            { width: FRAME_WIDTH, height: FRAME_HEIGHT },
            { width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight },
        );
        this._application!.view.width = FRAME_WIDTH * ratio;
        this._application!.view.height = FRAME_HEIGHT * ratio;
        this._application!.stage.scale.x = ratio;
        this._application!.stage.scale.y = ratio;
    }
}
```

Here's `optimalFitRatio`:

```
import ScreenSize from '@/app/util/ScreenSize';

export default function optimalFitRatio(originalSize: ScreenSize, fitToSize: ScreenSize): number {
    const horizontalRatio = fitToSize.width / originalSize.width;
    const verticalRatio = fitToSize.height / originalSize.height;
    return Math.min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
}
```

---

https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/9661